# count by value in array of objects in javascript using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects as follows:

```
var input_array = [{
    role_name: 'Full Stack Developer',
    position_id: 'b0f00e68-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1',
    email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com',
    application_id: '1dd45634-c283-4a96-a28a-d8a63c418329',
    state: 'qualified',
    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },
{
    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',
    position_id: '090276f0-3fca-4b2a-85ed-697d21c405a0',
    email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com',
    application_id: 'aa7fe2dd-b141-4c64-8350-a1d57bfaa502',
    state: 'interview',
    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },
{
    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',
    position_id: '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1',
    email_address: 'xyz.recruiter@gmail.com',
    application_id: '166da0ac-aaf1-400d-9a62-e37962f66653',
    state: 'interview',
    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },
{
    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',
    position_id: '090276f0-3fca-4b2a-85ed-697d21c405a0',
    email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com',
    application_id: 'da09a617-8e82-43c0-b1ea-725110a2c4cb',
    state: 'interview',
    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },
{
    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',
    position_id: '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1',
    email_address: 'xyz.recruiter@gmail.com',
    application_id: '1d55a51a-ecd1-43ea-9cf4-fed101dbebda',
    state: 'offer',
    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },
{
    role_name: 'Micro Space Planner',
    position_id: 'fe30930f-7d9f-4953-8939-6d9924462b2b',
    email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com',
    application_id: '293bd084-64f0-4c83-9b5d-aa304e44f066',
    state: 'screening',
    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },
{
    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',
    position_id: '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1',
    email_address: 'xyz.recruiter@gmail.com',
    application_id: '2adc5236-989d-49f2-ab3e-cb7e42798b77',
    state: 'qualified',
    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },
{
    role_name: 'Micro Space Planner',
    position_id: 'fe30930f-7d9f-4953-8939-6d9924462b2b',
    email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com',
    application_id: '293bd084-64f0-4c83-9b5d-aa304e44f066',
    state: 'screening',
    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },
{
    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',
    position_id: '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1',
    email_address: 'xyz.recruiter@gmail.com',
    application_id: '2adc5236-989d-49f2-ab3e-cb7e42798b77',
    state: 'qualified',
    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' }]
```

I want to count the object with the state as offer and interview corresponding to each and every position. I am using npm `lodash` library.

I have checked a few questions on SO about the group by and count using the filter but in my case position id is dynamic. So I can not set the specific value of position_id using which I can group the objects.

e.g.  position_id as '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-8b3962550ce7' contains 1 offer and 1 interview

Expected Output:

```
{
    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',
    position_id: '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1',
    email_address: 'xyz.recruiter@gmail.com',
    offer_count: 1,
    interview_count: 1
},
{
    role_name: 'Micro Space Planner',
    position_id: 'fe30930f-7d9f-4953-8939-6d9924462b2b',
    email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com',
    offer_count: 0,
    interview_count:0
},
{
    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',
    position_id: '090276f0-3fca-4b2a-85ed-697d21c405a0',
    email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com',
    offer_count: 0,
    interview_count:2
}
```

Comment: So the second code sample is your expected output?

Comment: yes,  second is for expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce` to group the objects by `id` and the function `Object.values` to extract the grouped objects.

```js
let input_array = [{    role_name: 'Full Stack Developer',    position_id: 'b0f00e68-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1',    email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com',    application_id: '1dd45634-c283-4a96-a28a-d8a63c418329',    state: 'qualified',    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },{    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',    position_id: '090276f0-3fca-4b2a-85ed-697d21c405a0',    email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com',    application_id: 'aa7fe2dd-b141-4c64-8350-a1d57bfaa502',    state: 'interview',    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },{    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',    position_id: '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1',    email_address: 'xyz.recruiter@gmail.com',    application_id: '166da0ac-aaf1-400d-9a62-e37962f66653',    state: 'interview',    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },{    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',    position_id: '090276f0-3fca-4b2a-85ed-697d21c405a0',    email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com',    application_id: 'da09a617-8e82-43c0-b1ea-725110a2c4cb',    state: 'interview',    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },{    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',    position_id: '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1',    email_address: 'xyz.recruiter@gmail.com',    application_id: '1d55a51a-ecd1-43ea-9cf4-fed101dbebda',    state: 'offer',    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },{    role_name: 'Micro Space Planner',    position_id: 'fe30930f-7d9f-4953-8939-6d9924462b2b',    email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com',    application_id: '293bd084-64f0-4c83-9b5d-aa304e44f066',    state: 'screening',    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },{    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',    position_id: '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1',    email_address: 'xyz.recruiter@gmail.com',    application_id: '2adc5236-989d-49f2-ab3e-cb7e42798b77',    state: 'qualified',    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },{    role_name: 'Micro Space Planner',    position_id: 'fe30930f-7d9f-4953-8939-6d9924462b2b',    email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com',    application_id: '293bd084-64f0-4c83-9b5d-aa304e44f066',    state: 'screening',    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' },{    role_name: 'Delivery Representative',    position_id: '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1',    email_address: 'xyz.recruiter@gmail.com',    application_id: '2adc5236-989d-49f2-ab3e-cb7e42798b77',    state: 'qualified',    closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' }],
    result = Object.values(input_array.reduce((a, {state, role_name, position_id, email_address}) => { 
      a[position_id] = (a[position_id] || {role_name, position_id, email_address, offer_count: 0, interview_count: 0});
      a[position_id].offer_count += (state === 'offer');
      a[position_id].interview_count += (state === 'interview');
      return a;
    }, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `reduce` and `map`, either the native JS or lodash versions. First, reduce bins up the records by position id, then you map over the object entries to produce the array you want.

```
Object.entries(input_arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!acc[item.position_id]) {
    acc[item.position_id] = {
      interview_count: 0,
      offer_count: 0,
      email_address: item.email_address,
      role_name: item.role_name
    };
  }

  if (item.state === 'interview') acc[item.position_id].interview_count += 1;
  if (item.state === 'offer') acc[item.position_id].offer_count += 1;
  return acc;
}, {})).map(([position_id, {email_address, interview_count, offer_count, role_name}]) => {
  return {
    position_id,
    email_address,
    interview_count,
    offer_count,
    role_name
  };
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qp7z2vk/)

Comment: Is variable arr stands for input_array? and what is Object.entries there? and Will the complete code be in a function and I have to call the function using parameters as input_array ? can you please modify the code accordingly?

Comment: @Deep yes to the first question. [MDN entry on Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: I appreciate if you please can make jsfiddle for this problem

Comment: @Deep done. See my updated answer. You can run it and inspect the result array in the console.

Comment: Ok, I will check. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the original array into a new hash object to hold a map of the positions and count the states of the input array.

```
let interviews = input_array.reduce(function(acc, cur) {  // go over every applicant
    if (!acc[cur.position_id]) {
        acc[cur.position_id] = {      //set initial object if the job is new
            role_name: cur.role_name,
            ...,
            offer_count: 0,
            interview_count:0
        }
    }

    if (cur.state === "offer") {
        acc[cur.position_id].offer_count++;
    } else if (cur.state === "interview") {
        acc[cur.position_id].interview_count++;
    }

    return acc;
}, {});
```

Reduce is a native JS array method, so you actually don't need to use lodash or any external libraries for this computation

Comment: Does not conform to desired output.

Comment: That is correct, although you can easily transform a hash object into an array using `arr = Object.values(obj)`, i'd still recommend keeping the hash format as it is a better way to store a list of unique job_ids. more easily accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with something like this without lodash and via `reduce`, `Object.assign` & `Object.values`:

```js
var data = [{ role_name: 'Full Stack Developer', position_id: 'b0f00e68-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1', email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com', application_id: '1dd45634-c283-4a96-a28a-d8a63c418329', state: 'qualified', closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' }, { role_name: 'Delivery Representative', position_id: '090276f0-3fca-4b2a-85ed-697d21c405a0', email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com', application_id: 'aa7fe2dd-b141-4c64-8350-a1d57bfaa502', state: 'interview', closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' }, { role_name: 'Delivery Representative', position_id: '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1', email_address: 'xyz.recruiter@gmail.com', application_id: '166da0ac-aaf1-400d-9a62-e37962f66653', state: 'interview', closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' }, { role_name: 'Delivery Representative', position_id: '090276f0-3fca-4b2a-85ed-697d21c405a0', email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com', application_id: 'da09a617-8e82-43c0-b1ea-725110a2c4cb', state: 'interview', closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' }, { role_name: 'Delivery Representative', position_id: '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1', email_address: 'xyz.recruiter@gmail.com', application_id: '1d55a51a-ecd1-43ea-9cf4-fed101dbebda', state: 'offer', closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' }, { role_name: 'Micro Space Planner', position_id: 'fe30930f-7d9f-4953-8939-6d9924462b2b', email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com', application_id: '293bd084-64f0-4c83-9b5d-aa304e44f066', state: 'screening', closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' }, { role_name: 'Delivery Representative', position_id: '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1', email_address: 'xyz.recruiter@gmail.com', application_id: '2adc5236-989d-49f2-ab3e-cb7e42798b77', state: 'qualified', closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' }, { role_name: 'Micro Space Planner', position_id: 'fe30930f-7d9f-4953-8939-6d9924462b2b', email_address: 'abc.recruiter@gmail.com', application_id: '293bd084-64f0-4c83-9b5d-aa304e44f066', state: 'screening', closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' }, { role_name: 'Delivery Representative', position_id: '12345678-5adc-4209-aec2-9c4962550ab1', email_address: 'xyz.recruiter@gmail.com', application_id: '2adc5236-989d-49f2-ab3e-cb7e42798b77', state: 'qualified', closing_date: '2018-10-28 06:30:00' }]

const combine = (r = {offer_count: 0, interview_count: 0}, c) => {
   r.offer_count += c.state ==='offer'
   r.interview_count += c.state === 'interview'
   let {application_id, state, closing_date, ...rest} = c
   return Object.assign(r, rest)
}
const countEm = d => Object.values(d.reduce((r,c) => (r[c.position_id] = combine(r[c.position_id], c), r), {}))

console.log(countEm(data))
```